# Session problems

Tags: session, refresh

I have a page that pulls up records from the database. If you click a record for further information then click the back button on the browser, the page says:

"Warning: Page has Expired"

and you have to refresh the page before the data shows up.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What web technology (php,asp.net...) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. It will help prevent scenarios where you have to resubmit form data.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with form data. I'm using a master-detail page whereby the master page displays a list of summaries for different products while the detailed page displays the detailed information.

Comment: Hmm, this warning message is normally due to form data (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183763). "Warning: Page has Expired
The page you requested was created using information you submitted in a form. This page is no longer available. As a security precaution, Internet Explorer does not automatically resubmit your information for you."

Answer (score 0):

When you use HttPSession you shouldn't use back button, because you should resubmit last invokation, infact warning "Warning: Page has Expired" occurs because you've resubmitted request but some parameters of request are expired.

Create a mechanism to forward in prevous page.

Bye

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can create a mechanism to forward in the previous page, as you explained above. Probably the usage of redirect will do? but where will I place the redirect statement in my code.

Comment: As per the mechanism to forward in previous page, can I use 
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=http://www.mysite/the_url">